# Python joining a string with a list format

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a tuple in format of a string: `{'biz': ['baz'], 'bar': ['foo']}`. I want to convert it to `biz=baz&bar=foo` manually. This is what I tried

```
'&'.join(("{}={}".format(key, value[0]) for key, value in s.items()))
```

I get an attribute error, though:

```
AttributeError: 'ParseResult' object has no attribute 'items'
```

how can I get a solution to the problem?

Comment: If s is a string, it doesn't have .items() property.

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska how can I convert it to a list?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to convert the dict (not tuple) to a url format, why not use existing tools for that?

Comment: `s = {'biz': ['baz'], 'bar': ['foo']}`, `'&'.join(("{}={}".format(key, value[0]) for key, value in s.items()))` seems to work for me. Please verify.

Comment: @Luis it doesn't work.

Comment: Verify here https://repl.it/JhOS/0

Comment: @Luis OP has the string ```"{'biz': ['baz'], 'bar': ['foo']}"```, not the dictionary ```{'biz': ['baz'], 'bar': ['foo']}```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to dictionary format first by:

```
import ast 
evaluated = ast.literal_eval('{'biz': ['baz'], 'bar': ['foo']}')
```

and then perform:

```
'&'.join(("{}={}".format(key, value[0]) for key, value in evaluated.items()))
```

Comment: Thanks. But why to a dictionary and not to a list?

Comment: Lists don't have ```.items()```;  the string you have looks very much like a dict (not a list or a tuple).

Comment: because your literal is representation of a dictionary

Comment: @user55449 well, no. Each key has a single value, so I don't know why I should use a dictionary.

Comment: lists doesn't have keys and your literal is a representation of a dictionary, list would look differently
You are trying to use a dictionary in your example.

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska keys are some integers which start from 0 and increase of 1. Why not a list? The values of the keys won't be more than 1, in my case.

Comment: Your string literal looks like a dictionary and is also interpreted by python as a dictionary ( ast.literal_eval() will evaluate a literal to list if you pass there a literal of a list), it has keys which are strings, it has curly brackets. If you want to convert it to a list you need to specify wheter you want to loose your string keys or store them somehow.

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska yep, I need to store them somehow

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska good work, I'm choosing dictionaries. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution that operates directly on the string. It's a little ugly, and some regex would make working with the string easier. Besides, Agata's solution is better, because it takes advantage of the fact that the string you gave is the literal representation of a dictionary. This means that if you pasted `d = {'biz': ['baz'], 'bar': ['foo']}` into a Python interpreter, then `d` would be a dictionary whose keys are strings and values lists of strings.

```
s.replace(',','&').replace(':','=').replace('[','').replace('{','').replace('}','').replace(']','').replace("'",'').replace(" ",'')
```

OP, you should read some tutorials about basic Python data structures.

Comment: This is a bit hacky though, I think it's good to convert it to an actual list and work on it.

Comment: You've pasted a _string_ that looks like a _dictionary_, called it a _tuple_, and said you want to convert it to a _list_ and then to a _string_. Until you clarify your question, the answers will be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use regex, `"{}={}&{}={}".format(*re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9_-]+", my_string))`.

Or `json.loads` if you do `my_string.replace("'",'"')` first.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want, though I am not sure I understand your question perfectly.

```
"&".join(["=".join([k,v[0]]) for k,v in s.items()])
```